# Web app server: How to show a document that the user doesn't has access

Tags: app, office-web-apps, web

I 'm designing a system with 100s of sites,1,000s of SP groups 1.000s of lists and 100.000s of documents. After a certain period of time, the documents will "move" from their current location  to a different (sharepoint web application - record management?) archive site, and being replaced with "link to a document".

An SQL server will store the permissions of the archived documents, because with so many documents the limit of 50.000 unique permissions will be reached very qyickly. The SQL table will have two columns:the GUID of the document and a A.D. group that should have READ rights. An http handler will decide if the user is elligible to see a document and then call web app server to show it. So, the web app server will show a document that the user doesn't has access. Is this possible?

I could copy the desired document  to a "scratch" list, but I wouldn't want that.

Comment: is archive site on sharepoint or somewhere else? also how you store the permission in sql?

Comment: I have added these information to the question

Comment: Why can't the user have access to the document in the archive site?

Comment: Because there's a limits of 50.000 unique permissions

Comment: 50.000 ACLs, not necessarily 50.000 unique permissions. If two documents have permissions assigned to the same group it only counts as 1 - at least that's how I've interpreted it so far.

Comment: You are right. Yes, the list in the archive list should have more than 50.000 ACLs. At least 2-200 SP groups  could have READ access to a document

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to tell OWA to let a user through if he doesn't have access to the file in SharePoint - so I'll keep and eye out to how you solve this. You could try moving your HTTP Handler to process the OWA requests to the files and BLOCK UNDESIRED access instead of allowing desired access. That would, sadly, imply having SharePoint think everyone can see a file, when they can't

Comment: I guess you are right...